# code throwing pandas error and Import get_handle error on running

Tags: pandas, import, pycharm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91913\Desktop\Study material\MINOR PROJECT CODE FILES\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import (
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel import (
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel._base import (
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers.readers import (
  File "C:\Users\91913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 26, in <module>
    import get_handle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_handle'
```

I'm facing this error how to resolve this.

1. I tried checking if all necessary libraries have been installed or not.
2. I tried installing get_handle which showed me an error.

Comment: "*I tried installing get_handle which showed me an error.*" -> you should probably show the detailed error…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the same thing, happening to me, try, to take a look of you don't have multiple pandas versions by:"   pip list | grep pandas", if yes uninstall them by this"   pip uninstall pandas" and then reinstall pandas. Hope it helped. And if not, than I doubted, that another library you are using needs the pandas but older version, where the get_handle  method was, if yes, try and update all libraries you are using, but it doesn't need to necessarily work, cause some of the libraries, couldn't be maintained.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).